# How work BroadcastReceiver whith SQLite databases in ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite

How work BroadcastReceiver whith SQLite databases in ANDROID
Hi!
My goal is to write a program to block incoming calls. A list of numbers stored in the database. The program should work on the following schedule:
1) Registers incoming call
2) He takes an incoming phone number
3) Does the SQL query the database for the presence of this number
4) if the number is found in the database - completing a call
Below I have pasted the code that is used for this but when you call the program crashes with an error.
Please help me! I've tried everything! head boils: (((((

MY COD:

```
public class BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private Cursor mCursor;
private static final String[] mContent = new String[] {
MainDBHelper._ID, MainDBHelper.COL_NAME};

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";
public static final String COL_NAME = "first_name";
public MainDBHelper mainDBHelper;
/////////////////// block telephone ///////////////////////
     Context context;
    private ITelephony telephonyService;
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         SQLiteDatabase db = mainDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // Enable my SQLite database
         try {
         Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
           String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number"); // get number of incomin call
           //--------------------------
           mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { }, COL_NAME + "=?",
                   new String[] {phoneNumber}, null, null, null, null);// search request to my SQLite database
           String COUNT_IMAGE = Integer.toString(mCursor.getCount());
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
           if (mCursor.getCount()>0){ // if in database contain of data the .......
              String data = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME));// FOUND NUMBER
              Log.d(data, phoneNumber);

              if ((phoneNumber != null)) { 
                  setResultData(null); 
                    telephonyService.endCall(); // incoming call has bloced
                    Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
                 }

          }
           else{}

               }catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

MY ERROR WHEN INCOMING CALL:

```
   02-02 15:07:43.254: E/AndroidRuntime(22304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 15:07:43.254: E/AndroidRuntime(22304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.example.BroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 15:07:43.254: E/AndroidRuntime(22304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
02-02 15:07:43.254: E/AndroidRuntime(22304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

MY MainDBHelper code:

```
public class MainDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
        implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "first_name";
   // public static final String COL_PHONE = "phone";

    public static final Uri URI_CONTENT
        = Uri.parse("content://com.example.stopdolg.MainDBProvider/contact");
    public static final int URI_CODE = 1;
    public static final int URI_CODE_ID = 2;

    public MainDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, MainDBProvider.DB_CONTACTS3, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
         "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='" 
                + TABLE_NAME + "'", null);

        try {
            if (c.getCount()==0) {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME 
                        + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                        + COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + " TEXT);");

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();




            }
        }
        finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(
            SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP! :)

Comment: Have you declared it in the `AndroidManifest.XML` ?

Comment: Yes:  <receiver  android:name=".StopDolgBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Your `mainDBHelper` is null. Initialize `MainDBHelper` class.

Comment: Seems `mainDBHelper` is `null`, I can't see where it has been initialized

Comment: You must...............

Comment: How should I initialize MainDBHelper??

Comment: Show constructor for your MainDBHelper class

Comment: Code added above, refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your class in `onReceive()` method before you open(enable) your database:

```
mainDBHelper = new MainDBHelper(context);
```